# How to combine and negate these two patterns together?

Tags: vim

In VIM, I want to delete any lines that are not 2 or 3 characters.

```
:g/^..$/d
:g/^...$/d
```

Those delete 2 or 3 character lines. How to combine the two into one and negate it, namely 'don't delete 2 or 3 character lines'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following would be my regex of choice

```
:v/\v^.{2,3}$/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pMP6YsTq/aSMe4VkU/5f9/Qy4jIy5jY2MuEyDgMgUBAA)

Options: Case insensitive

- [Assert position at the beginning of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match any single character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{2,3}`

  - [Between 2 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,3}`
- [Assert position at the very end of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`:v`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Av) to execute a command on lines that do not match a pattern.

This requires that you use a single pattern though... Which in your case you can easily do by using the [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3D) modifier to optionally match the last item.

So to delete all lines with either 2 or 3 characters, you can use:

```
:g/^...\=$/d
```

And to delete all lines *except* those with either 2 or 3 characters:

```
:v/^...\=$/d
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know about `\=`. That is not regex though, is it? The regex equivalent would be `?`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers See the link to Vim help on Vim regexes. Vim also takes `\?` for optional. Under "very magic", you can also omit the backslash.

Comment: I've looked at the link but I doubt I'm ever going to master the mixing of regex and vim modifiers (let alone understand when to use it).

Answer (score 2):

How about "delete all lines with less than two or more than three characters"?

```
:g/^.\{,1}$\|^.\{4,}/d
```